# javascript get dynamic hidden element from form

Tags: javascript

I have a form that looks something like this

```
<FORM>
    <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='search0' VALUE='a'> 
    <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='search1' VALUE='b'>
    ... etc 
    <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='search100' VALUE='abc'>
</FORM>
```

In my javascript i would like to do something along the lines of :

```
 for (i=0;i<=100;i++) { 
     document.forms[0].search+i+.value = '';
 }
```

Clearly this is not valid syntax, I am just not sure how to go about getting all 100 of my hidden inputs and change all their values to empty. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: thanks for formatting the FORM for me j08691, i didnt know how to properly format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `.0` would not be valid syntax - therefore you use `[0]` because you can put any expression inside such brackets (e.g. numbers, strings). Indeed, you can also use the `+` operator inside since `+` can be applied to expressions. This solves your issue:

```
document.forms[0]["search" + i].value = '';
```

You could also use `["forms"]` instead of `.forms`, etc. Basically, the `.` notation is only a subset of the `[]` notation.

Comment: thank you for fast reply, this was exactly what i was looking for. Will mark as correct in 5 minutes when the website allows me to

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery "almost but not really" equivalent would be something like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* all input that has a name that starts with search */
  $("input[name^=search]").each(function (){
    /* set the value to empty */
    $(this).val('');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It would not be completely functionally equal, but anyway you don't need `.each`.